# Better way to handle enum change methods?

Tags: c#, enums

Initially, my hope was to have some sort of encapsulation with enums, but apparently that isn't [yet possible with C#](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2006/01/05/classenum.aspx). My purpose was to store some sort of data with the enum. Ideally, having an enum of objects would have been great. But there's apparently no way to do that. So I created a state class, a public enum, and made a public getter/setter with a setter that initializes a method in which i can populate objects as a property.
I'm wondering if there's a slightly better way. The ideal solution for me would be to set a state (enum) the normal way:

```
car.State = CarStates.Idle;
```

and then access more data about that state like so:

```
string message = car.State.Message();
```

But this would involve attaching a property to the State enum. Is there any cool trick to achieve this effect? Are enums the only way you can make **switchable**, singleton-like values by simply adding `.Idle` to the end?

Here's the code as I have it now that keeps the state info at one level by adding a layer, which is passable, but feels redundant when declaring something like `car.Mode.State = CarModeStates.Idle;`.

```
class Car
{
    public CarState Mode;

    public Car()
    {
        Mode = new CarState();
    }
}

class CarState //holds any metadata for given enum value
{
    private int _EnumInt;
    private string _Message;
    private bool _IsError = false;

    public CarModeStates State
    { 
        get { return (CarModeStates)_EnumInt; } 
        set { _EnumInt = (int)value; InitializeState(value); } 
    }
    public string Message { get { return _Message; } }
    public bool IsError { get { return _IsError; } }

    public void InitializeState(CarModeStates? cs)
    {
        switch (cs)
        {
            case (CarModeStates.Off):
                {
                    _Message = "Car is off.";
                    _IsError = false;
                    break;
                }
            case (CarModeStates.Idle):
                {
                    _Message = "Car is idling.";
                    _IsError = false;
                    break;
                }
            case (CarModeStates.Drive):
                {
                    _Message = "Car is driving.";
                    _IsError = false;
                    break;
                }
            case (CarModeStates.Accident):
                {
                    _Message = "CRASH!";
                    _IsError = true;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}

public enum CarModeStates
{
    Off,
    Idle,
    Drive,
    Accident,
}

//And from the outside:
class SomeController
{
    Car car = new Car();
    public string GetStateMessage()
    {
        car.Mode.State = CarModeStates.Idle;

        return car.Mode.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the way you use it violates SRP. Message should not be bound to enum, but should be part of some localization system. And IsError is context-specific. It should be only in place where this relation is required.

Comment: The message itself I want to relate to the context of the enum. I created this code just to test a simple version of what I'd like to do. For instance, the message might be what triggered the state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried an extension method?  In a static class, define:

```
public static string Message( this CarStates value )
{
    switch (value) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can use `this` in a static method, correct?

Comment: @Ryan: This isn't "using" a `this` object, it is a special syntax involving the `this` keyword [called an extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx).

Comment: OK, I need to look more into that.

Comment: Extension methods achieve the effect I desired.

Comment: I'm seeing that I can't use extension methods to set private fields. That is definitely one drawback.

Comment: @Ryan: No, probably not.  But enums don't have private fields anyway.  And types that do, you can use normal methods.

Comment: Then you lose the switch statement. Skeet did a blog about all this years ago in my searches (linked in my original post). It would be nice if there was a way to enum types somehow. Ah well. I suppose the choice is extension methods if they can be done as static, and a separate state class if you want fields and methods beyond the enum.

Answer (score 3):

Regular enums in C# are often not as problematic as your question suggests. Just make sure your `switch` statement has a `default` case that throws an `ArgumentException` to make sure you're getting one of the valid values. You have to be careful with the literal value `0` (which is implicitly convertible to any enum type), but other than that an `enum` in C# does offer substantial type safety at the API level.

C# enums perform *substantially* better than fully-encapsulated enums like Java uses. There are a few additional details to be aware of (e.g. values out of range), but they rarely cause problems in practice.

---

Java-style enum classes are easy to create in C#. **Edit: except for the fact that you cannot use the `switch` statement on the C# version of an enum like this.**

1. Make the class `sealed`.
2. Make sure the class has at least 1 explicit constructor, and make sure all constructors are `private`.
3. Translate members like the following:

Java:

```
enum Color { RED, GREEN, BLUE }
```

C#:

```
private class Color {
    public static readonly Color RED = new Color();
    public static readonly Color GREEN = new Color();
    public static readonly Color BLUE = new Color();

    private Color() { }
}
```

If you really want to mimic Java, you can get clever by creating an `Enum<T>` abstract base class for enums of this form that maintains an `Ordinal` property, and also create a static `Values` property like the following in the `Color` class:

```
public Color[] Values { get { return new[] { RED, GREEN, BLUE }; } }
```

Comment: I was just gonna ask about the switch statement. Thanks.

Comment: @RyanJMcGowan I added a paragraph at the beginning to address the `switch` statement.

Comment: I know I could use enums in the conventional sense. I'm not going for performance, but rather an efficient and intuitive way to extend information off an enum by going `EnumName.EnumValue.MoreData`. My code achieves that, but I had to add a layer.

Comment: If you're willing to use `MoreData()` instead of `MoreData`, you can use an `enum` along with a class containing extension methods. And you can use a `switch` statement to implement the extension methods.

Comment: Correction: I sort of achieve the intuitive part, but I still can't access information by going down a level from the enum, which I'm sure is impossible.

Comment: The Methods vs. Field isn't an issue. It's going below the enum that I have an issue with. Do extension methods do that to enums?? I'll start learning more about them.

Comment: Extension methods did do what I was trying to achieve. I marked Ben's answer as correct since his answer was specific to that resolution.

Answer (score 1):

An extension method combined with a dictionary might be a solution instead of a switch statement.

```
public static class CarExtensionMethods
{
    public static string Message(this CarStates value)
    {
        return carStateDictionary[value];
    }

    private static readonly Dictionary<CarStates, string> carStateDictionary;

    static CarExtensionMethods()
    {
        carStateDictionary = new Dictionary<CarStates, string>();

        carStateDictionary.Add(CarStates.Off, "Car is off.");
        carStateDictionary.Add(CarStates.Idle, "Car is idling.");
        carStateDictionary.Add(CarStates.Drive, "Car is driving.");
        carStateDictionary.Add(CarStates.Accident, "CRASH!");
    }
}
```

The usage is pretty straight forward:

```
CarStates state = CarState.Idle;
Console.WriteLine(state.Message());  //writes "Car is idling."
```

Also just as a side note, typically `enum` names should only plural when they have the `[Flags]` attribute.  The point is to indicate they can have more than one state.  A more stylistically appropriate name for your enum is `CarState` since it cannot have more than one state as a time.

Comment: -1: The use of `Dictionary` here adds substantial, completely unnecessary overhead. Instead, use a `switch` statement in the implementation of `Message()`.

Comment: I disagree with @Sam Harwell. Adding more states in the future means the code in the switch statement will have to be extended to cover the new states. This way will handle any new states as they come along, will it not?

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to **just** use `Enum` values then you can create your own attributes to provide the extra meta data.

The below example works **but** I personally would not model my domain this way.

```
// sample test app
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var carState = CarModeStates.Accident;

        // the call to get the meta data could and probably should be stored in a local variable
        Console.WriteLine(carState.GetMetaData().Message);
        Console.WriteLine(carState.GetMetaData().IsError);
        Console.WriteLine(carState.GetMetaData().IsUsingPetrol);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Extended enum example

```
// enum with meta data
public enum CarModeStates
{
    [CarStatus("Car is off."), IsError(false), IsUsingPetrol(false)]
    Off,

    [CarStatus("Car is idling."), IsError(false), IsUsingPetrol(true)]
    Idle,

    [CarStatus("Car is driving."), IsError(false), IsUsingPetrol(true)]
    Drive,

    [CarStatus("CRASH!"), IsError(true), IsUsingPetrol(false)]
    Accident
}
```

Custom attributes to decorate the enum

```
public interface IAttribute<out T>
{
    T Description { get; }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class CarStatusAttribute : Attribute, IAttribute<string>
{
    private readonly string _value;

    public CarStatusAttribute(string value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return _value; }
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class IsErrorAttribute : Attribute, IAttribute<bool>
{
    private readonly bool _value;

    public IsErrorAttribute(bool value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public bool Description
    {
        get { return _value; }
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class IsUsingPetrolAttribute : Attribute, IAttribute<bool>
{
    private readonly bool _value;

    public IsUsingPetrolAttribute(bool value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public bool Description
    {
        get { return _value; }
    }
}
```

Extension method(s) to get the meta data about the enum.

```
public static class CarModeStatesExtensions
{
    public static CarModeStateModel GetMetaData(this CarModeStates value)
    {
        var model = new CarModeStateModel
            {
                Message = value.GetDescriptionFromEnumValue<string>(typeof (CarStatusAttribute)),
                IsError = value.GetDescriptionFromEnumValue<bool>(typeof(IsErrorAttribute)),
                IsUsingPetrol = value.GetDescriptionFromEnumValue<bool>(typeof (IsUsingPetrolAttribute))
            };

        return model;
    }
}

public class CarModeStateModel
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool IsError { get; set; }
    public bool IsUsingPetrol { get; set; }
}

public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static T GetDescriptionFromEnumValue<T>(this CarModeStates value, Type attributeType)
    {
        var attribute = value.GetType()
            .GetField(value.ToString())
            .GetCustomAttributes(attributeType, false).SingleOrDefault();

        if (attribute == null)
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        return ((IAttribute<T>)attribute).Description;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was aware that attributes could achieve this, but I prefer to keep code in code blocks, and I admit I am not proficient at them yet. I knew as soon as I used the word "metadata" someone would suggest that. Thanks for taking the time for a detailed response.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need a "factory" like that:

```
public class CarState
{
    private string message;
    private bool error;

    public CarState(string message, bool error)
    {
        this.message = message;
        this.error = error;
    }

    public string Message
    {
        get { return this.message; }
    }

    public bool Error
    { 
        get { return this.error; }
    }
}

public static class CarStateFactory
{
    public enum CarStateId { Off, Idle, Driving, Accident }

    public static CarState GetCarState(CarStateId carStateId)
    {
        switch(carStateId)
        {
            case (CarStateId.Off):
                { return new CarState("Car is off", false); }

            //add more cases

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

With this you are able to set the state of your car by calling:

```
car.State = CarStateFactory.GetCarState(CarStateFactory.ID.Off); //ID.Idle, ID.Driving, ID.Accident
```

**AND**

You can access the message with `car.State.Message`.

EDIT:
Static getter for the CarStateFactory

```
public static CarState Idle
{
    get
    {
        return new CarState("Car is off", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be a tossup between my code and this. `car.Mode.State = CarModeStates.Idle;` looks a lot prettier, though.

Comment: True. You can always condense the code or move the enum where you think it fits better. Separating out the factory class was just to make it more clear for me.

Comment: I added the code for a static getter to my answer so you can do 
`CarStateFactoy.Idle`. I personally don't like how it looks, but you might want to try it. Then you can rename "CarStateFactory" to what ever you need.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old but for further visitors, rather than using an enum for this, maybe use a state manager where an object represents each state?

Abstract

```
/// <summary>
/// Defines the expected members of a state
/// </summary>
internal interface ICarState
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The message.
    /// </value>
    string Message { get; }
}
```

The base state

```
/// <summary>
/// The class that all car states should inherit from.
/// </summary>
internal abstract class CarBaseState : ICarState
{
    #region ICarState Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The message.
    /// </value>
    /// </exception>
    public abstract string Message { get; }

    #endregion
}
```

Implementation

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents the state when the car is off
/// </summary>
internal class OffState : CarBaseState
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The message.
    /// </value>
    /// </exception>
    public override string Message { get { return "Off"; } }
}

/// <summary>
/// Represents the state when the car is idling
/// </summary>
internal class IdleState : CarBaseState
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The message.
    /// </value>
    /// </exception>
    public override string Message { get { return "Idling"; } }
}
```

Manager

```
internal class CarStateManager
{
    #region Fields

    Dictionary<string, ICarState> _stateStore = null;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets (or privately sets) the state of the current.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The state of the current.
    /// </value>
    internal ICarState CurrentState { get; private set;  }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors and Initialisation

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="StateManager"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public CarStateManager()
    {
        _stateStore = new Dictionary<string, ICarState>();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a state.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stateId">The state identifier.</param>
    /// <param name="state">The state.</param>
    public void AddState(string stateId, ICarState state)
    {
        // Add the state to the collection
        _stateStore.Add(stateId, state);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Changes the state.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stateId">The state identifier.</param>
    public void ChangeState(string stateId)
    {

        // Set thr current state
        CurrentState = _stateStore[stateId];
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Program

```
class Program
{
    internal class StateKeys
    {
        public const string Off = "Off";
        public const string Idle = "Idle";
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Instantiate the state manager
        CarStateManager stateManager = new CarStateManager();

        // Add the states
        stateManager.AddState(StateKeys.Off, new OffState());
        stateManager.AddState(StateKeys.Idle, new IdleState());

        // Change the state and display the message
        stateManager.ChangeState(StateKeys.Off);
        Console.WriteLine(stateManager.CurrentState.Message);

        // Change the state and display the message
        stateManager.ChangeState(StateKeys.Idle);
        Console.WriteLine(stateManager.CurrentState.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Off
Idling
```

HTH!